# Isometric parameterization of curves

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, differential-forms, parametrization, isometry

In section 1.3 of "A Geometric Approach to Differential Forms", we want to integrate the function $f(x,y) = y^2$ on the top half of the unit circle,

For the 2 parameterizations of the top half of the unit circle:
$\phi_1 (a) = (a, \sqrt{1-a^2}), \space a \in [-1,1] $
$\phi_2 (t) = (\cos t, \sin t), \space t \in [0, \pi].$

We end up needing to do: $\int_{-1}^{1} f( \phi_1 (a)) \space |\frac{d\phi_1}{da}| \space da.$

Which is equivalent to: $\int_{0}^{\pi} f( \phi_2 (t)) \space |\frac{d\phi_2}{dt}| \space dt.$

As opposed to the naive approach of not including the absolute value factor in the integral (and this is how the author introduces a 1-form).
However it turns out that already the second parameterization gives the correct answer without the "correction" factor (because $|\frac{d\phi_2}{dt}|$ = 1), and this seems to be (as far as I can tell) because the second parameterization preserves distances *along the arc of the circle*, so for 2 points $ t_1 \& t_2 \in [0, \pi]$ with $\Delta t = t_2 - t_1$, then $\Delta \phi_2 (t) = r(t_2-t_1) = t_2-t_1$ (Because $r=1$) after  $\phi_2$ transformation, whereas $\phi_1$ doesn't have this property.

So my question is does this property of preserving the integral hold for all isometric embeddings? So ones that preserve only the metric and not just the distance as well?
(So that you can find a parameterization for (intrinsically) curved surfaces like the top half of the sphere that would preserve the integral?)

Comment: Integration with respect to arclength on a curve is less obviously the integral of a $1$-form ($ds$ is not a $1$-form), although once you orient the curve you can turn this into a $1$-form integration problem. For the top unit semicircle,  oriented counterclockwise, you can integrate $\omega = f(x,y)(-y\,dx+x\,dy)$.

Comment: The analogue of arclength parametrization for curves is hard to come by in higher dimensions. Basically, one has a local isometric parametrization by (a subset of) the plane if and only if the surface has zero curvature.

Comment: @TedShifrin oh I see, so the surface has to have 0 curvature, even if the isometry preserves the "metric" (I'm thinking of Nash isometric embedding that preserves the inner product on tangent spaces of Riemannian manifolds), so it necessarily has to preserve distance. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, the isometric embedding question has nothing to do with (local) parametrization!!